# How to modify bootstrap file according to language in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, i18next, next-i18next

i have a 2 languages in Next app
one of them is: rtl direction
and other is: ltr direction

How i can import bootstrap css file according to language (default css file or rtl file)

useEffect and useLayoutEffect is they are late and am dont do create loading page

[image]

Comment: You can import that `.css` in your stylesheet and try something like : `this.setState({stylePath: 'style.css'});`

Comment: Please make sure to post code as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).